# Https Website: CSS and JS files load in http and admin page does not load too

Tags: wp-admin, ssl, https

After enabling SSL the website loads in HTML. CSS and JS files load only in HTTP(view source) and the admin page does not load either.

Tried implementing all solutions like rewrite condition to force https, wp-config file, ssl plugins. Nothing works.

Now the entire website has mixed content of http(CSS and JS) and https(HTML).

Comment: Are the values for **siteurl** and **home** in the `wp_options` database table updated? If a multisite, then **siteurl** in the `wp_sitemeta` database table needs to be updated. These updates can be done using WordPress Admin pages. Alternatively, you can use the [wp_config.php constants](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-wp-config-php) **WP_HOME** and **WP_SITEURL**. The link to the WordPress help page [Changing The Site URL](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/) should be helpful.

Comment: Both site and home UTL have HTTPS in the wp_options table. The wp_config file has a slash at the end. Is this correct? 
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );

Comment: Hi @SecurityCIO. Please **back up database before using any of these suggestions**. **wp-config.php** example in WordPress docs does not use a trailing slash. You don't really need a plugin. **phpMyAdmin** has a good **Find and replace** utility found under the **Search** option (after selecting a table). The main tables and columns to update are: **wp_posts** (columns: *post_content*, *guid*), **wp_postmeta** (*meta_value*), **wp_options** (*option_value*), (if multisite: **wp_sitemeta**: *meta_value*). Use steps **#3** and **#4** in ray-happyforms's answer (don't just search for http://).

Comment: Also, if using your own custom plugins that enqueue JavaScript and CSS with [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) or [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) make sure the **src** parameter is using **https://** if absolute URLs are used. Updates do not necessarily require changing `.htaccess` unless you've already made changes that need to be reversed. If updating tables manually using phpMyAdmin's Find and replace, check to see if URLs exist in other database tables like **wp_termmeta**.

Comment: Nothing worked with EC2. Succeded with AWS Lightsail to handle things on its own. I'm not a developer, probably I didn't handle it well. But thanks for all the support Kofeigen.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you're having a "**Mixed Content**" error, and it happens when a site that's supposed to be served over **HTTPS** (secure) is also serving some of its content over **HTTP** (non-secure). In your case, it appears that your CSS and JavaScript files are being served over HTTP, which is causing the problem.

First, ensure that your website's URL in the WordPress settings is using HTTPS. You can do this by going to "Settings" > "General" in the WordPress admin area. Both the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" should start with `https://`.

If that's already correct, or if changing it doesn't fix the issue, you'll need to replace all the HTTP URLs in your database with HTTPS (if you haven't tried it yet). Note that this should be done carefully, as making mistakes in your database can break your site. So to do that, you'll need to use a plugin like **[Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)**

Here's some step-by-step that you can follow as a guide:

1. Install and activate the Better Search Replace plugin.
2. Go to "Tools" > "Better Search Replace" in your WordPress admin area.
3. In the "**Search for**" field, enter your site's URL with `http://` (e.g., **http**://yourdomain.com).
4. In the "**Replace with**" field, enter your site's URL with `https://` (e.g., **https**://yourdomain.com).
5. Select all the tables.
6. Run a test first to make sure everything is working correctly. To do this, check the "**Run as dry run?**" option.  If it is, uncheck the "**Run as dry run?**" option and run the replacement.

Remember to deactivate and delete the **Better Search Replace** plugin when you're done using it.

And if you're using a caching plugin, don't forget to clear your site's cache and your browser's cache to make sure you're seeing the latest changes of your site.

If you are not comfortable with changing database values using the **Better Search Replace** plugin, you can also try using the [**Really Simple SSL**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) plugin to force your WordPress installation to use HTTPS on all of its pages and resources.

Comment: Tried both the plugins but nothing works. Surprisingly, I can load the admin dashboard through the IP address(http://1.2.3.4/wp-admin) but not through a domain like https://example.com/wp-admin. The site and home URL have HTTPS, confirmed it through PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: The admin dashboard does not load with the IP address now. Which instruction is correct for the problem, Can you suggest the right one from [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/administration-over-ssl/#rewrite-rules-for-the-insecure-host)

Comment: @SecurityCIO I highly suspected your issue is mixed content error, so the suggestions I provided should have fixed your issue. 

It's hard to tell the right instruction for the next step without really seeing the actual site and experiencing the issue. If you can, please share your URL so that people can take a look and help you properly.

Comment: Couldn't fix it through any of the methods. As a last step used AWS Lightsail to handle things on its own. It works well now. Thanks for all the suggestions Ray